# Template issue with openxlsx using R

Tags: r, openxls

My goal is to construct an Excel spreadsheet that contains all of the formatting for my data and to only use openxlsx via R to write dataframes to the file.  However, when I tried to do so, the formatting in the file is overwritten.  I am calling the function in this manner:

```
writeDataTable(wb,1,wl, 1,2,colNames=FALSE, rowNames=FALSE, 
               tableStyle="none", withFilter = FALSE, 
               bandedRows=FALSE, stack = TRUE)
```

Please advise.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest that writeDataTable may be the cause of your problem as it applies formatting by definition.

> Write to a worksheet and format as an Excel table

I recommend testing with writeData.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  When I try,  writeData(wb=wb, sheet=1, x=wl, startCol=1,startRow=2,colNames=FALSE,rowNames=FALSE,
          borders="none" )
the formatting is overridden.

Comment: Perhaps more info is needed, like a reproducible example. Using writeData works for me consistently. Unless I have filters on the target Excel range. `writeData(wb, "RANK by ITEM", x, startRow = 3, colNames = FALSE)`